# Как передать данные методом Post axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я хочу передать значение в файл telegram.php методом post axios. Вот код:

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'telegram.php',
        data: {
            text: "alert"
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
```

Но мне передает почему-то разметку файла telegram.php, вместо значения "alert". Что я делаю не так?

```html
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Kiev");
    $date = date("H:i");
    $hour = date("H");
    if($_POST["text"]){
        if($_POST["text"]=="alert" && $hour>=6 && $hour<22){
            $text = "Сообщение1";
        }
        else if($_POST["text"]=="alert"){
            $text = "Сообщение2";
        }
        else if($_POST["text"]=="no_alert" && $hour>=6 && $hour<22){
            $text = "Сообщение3";
        }
        else if($_POST["text"]=="no_alert"){
            $text = "Сообщение4";
        }
        else if($_POST["text"]=="detonate"){
            $text = "Сообщение5";
        }
        else if($_POST["text"]=="artillery"){
            $text = "Сообщение6";
        }
        else if($_POST["text"]=="no_artillery"){
            $text = "Сообщение7";
        }
        
        $token = "54**************5qoXN-L4**********u8********YU";
        $chat_id = "-10016***5517"; //main
        
        $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id1}&parse_mode=html&text={$text}", "r");
        
        if($sendToTelegram){
        }
        else{
            echo "Ошибка!";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./telegram.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Сообщение</h2>
    <input type="submit" class="alert alert-sirena" id="alert" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="alert alert-no" id="no_alert" value="2">
    <input type="submit" class="alert alert-detonate" id="alert-detonate" value="3">
    <input type="submit" class="alert alert-artillery" id="alert-artillery" value="4">
    <input type="submit" class="alert alert-no_artillery" id="5" value="5">
    
    <style>
        body{
            font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 0 10px;
            height: 100vh;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        h2{
            text-align: center;
        }
        input{
            height: 80px;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            font-weight: 700;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        input:last-child{
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .alert-sirena,.alert-detonate,.alert-artillery{
            background-color: red;
        }
        
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        let Confirm_text;
        if(e.target.classList.contains("alert")){
            Confirm_text = confirm("Подтвердить");
            if(Confirm_text){
                let value = e.target.getAttribute("id");
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("text", value);
                var Xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                Xhr.open("POST", "./telegram.php");
                Xhr.send(formData);
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: axios тут ни при чём. Настраивайте сервер.

Comment: Наиболее вероятная причина: вы забыли написать `<?php` в начале файла telegram.php

Comment: Открывающий тег <?php присутствует. Делал все как и в официальной документации, но не работает.

Comment: В любом случае, проблема не js и axios, а в сервере и php

Comment: Можете показать содержимое файла telegram.php?

Comment: Да, уже. Я обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы в ответе получить "alert" надо вернуть (`return`) либо вывести (`echo`) данный ответ в вашем PHP-скрипте, например, вот так:

```
if($sendToTelegram) {
   return json_encode($_POST["text"]);
}
```

Comment: Может, я что-то не понял, но как мне получить этот "alert"? Я так думаю его нужно получать так как и ajax запрос :     $_POST["text"] (и должно вывести alert). Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Всё верно! Равно как вы получаете это значение в своём `if($_POST["text"]=="alert"`

Comment: Поправил ответ :)

Comment: Я проверил, но не работает. Сделал проверку if($_POST["text"]{echo "good";}, и не выводит сообщение, это значит, что POST запрос не приходит. Я сейчас кину скриншот, что у меня в консоле.(обновлю вопрос)

Comment: Добавил, передается разметка страницы в DATA, хотя я передавал "alert"

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте так

Comment: не работает, post запрос вообще не идёт . странно конечно 